# Cant remove image from the mentioned content notification(android)

Tags: android, notifications

I want to know how to delete icon image from content notification, image attached below  : 
 [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFsCv.png)

My code is as follows :

```
final NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

                mBuilder.setContentTitle("New Message with explicit intent");
                mBuilder.setContentText("New message from javacodegeeks received");
                mBuilder.setTicker("Explicit: New Message Received!");
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                mBuilder.setLargeIcon(result);

                NotificationManager myNotificationManager;
                myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                // pass the Notification object to the system
                myNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: What do you mean by deleting image?

Comment: @Jas i mean show notification without this image(1) http://i.imgur.com/rnSpKQS.png

Comment: Add the image directly instead of using imgur

Comment: @Jas i need load image for notification from url, and if i dont set `mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);` then bitmap image dont work `mBuilder.setLargeIcon(result);`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want image, then remove this:

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
mBuilder.setLargeIcon(result);
```

Comment: i want show notification without this image(1) i.imgur.com/rnSpKQS.png . If i remove `mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`, notifications not show.  `mBuilder.setLargeIcon(result);` - it set bitmap image from internet